# CSS Border Radius not working on iOS

Tags: ios, safari, css

I'm having some trouble with borders on iOS (safari).

I have an image (my gravatar) which I want to give a round border which is 10px solid and white.

To achieve this I have the HTML

```
<img src="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/b7c2d49748426791dc98b8214dfac9d1?s=500" class="img-circle" height="300" width="300">
```

and the CSS

```
.img-circle {
-webkit-border-radius: 500px;
-moz-border-radius: 500px;
border-radius: 500px;
border: solid 10px white;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2UT8v/2/

I'm using twitter's bootstrap and so the border-radius is being specified by their class .img-circle (that is why the radius is 500px) and then I've added the border weight and color.

This works well on a desktop browser (Chrome) but when viewing on iOS (safari on my iPad) it shows the 10px solid white border is still a square around the original image and the radius is applied after and so cuts off some of the border.

[image: Border In Chrome][image: Border In iOS]

Does anybody know how I can get the border to follow the radius in iOS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mEZEj/ Use `box-shadow` instead of `border`.

Clean solution: http://jsfiddle.net/TjUum/ Use a block `div` element with the avatar as the `background-image`. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I tried the clean solution and it caused issues with my layout so I've gone quick and dirty for now and I'll have a look into the clean one when I have more time.

Comment: Helping someone get a predefined template page working for a discord bot, this quick and dirty fix is a lifesaver

Comment: For accessibility reasons, background image should only be used in decorative situations. If the image is content, it should be an img so that screen readers “read” it correctly