# border-radius does not apply on mobile (iOS) on desktop and Android works

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: image on desktop border radius work]
[image: image on mobile(iOS) border radius not work]

border-radius does not apply on mobile (iOS), it works on desktop and Android

```css
.play {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 325px;
    height: 72px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(123deg, #ffb000 38%, #ffda87 49%, #ffb81b 56%, #ffdb8a 65%, #ffbb25 70%, #f5b933 81%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8520ff, #45018f), linear-gradient(123deg, #ffb000 38%, #ffda87 49%, #ffb81b 56%, #ffdb8a 65%, #ffbb25 70%, #f5b933 81%);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    color: white;
    margin: 160px auto 120px !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #fff !important;
    transition: all .3s ease;

  }
```

```html
<div class="play">Let's Play</div>
```

border-radius does not apply on mobile (iOS), it works on desktop and Android

Comment: are you talking about IOS app? or safari browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Border Radius not working on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326517/css-border-radius-not-working-on-ios)

Comment: on iOS it doesn't work on chrome or safari

Comment: not , it doesn't answer my question, with box shadow it works but I can't apply that gradient

Comment: remove `border-image-slice: 1;`, is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: `will-change: transform;`?

Comment: I replaced "1" -> "0" border-image-slice: 0; now he is working

Answer (score -1):

here are the useful links given below: you can see the solution in them,
you have to apply (Ios / Safari) Specific Media Queries to get your solution for border radius, Yes Safari browser behaves differently ,

[CSS media query to target only iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102792/css-media-query-to-target-only-ios-devices)

https://copyprogramming.com/howto/css-media-query-for-safari-only

Also it has to do some thing with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also as per Reddit latest

you can get your desired result by adding "(min-width: 1px)" in your media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) {
    * {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

I hope it will solve your problem